# Unique value in redis list/set

Tags: redis, nosql

I want to make a list of existing products in `redis` but I want to check if the product name already exists first (duplicate checking).

My list currently accepts duplicates, so: Can anyone help me to show how to add unique value in list?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Instead of using a list, use a set. Sets are containers for unique objects. Each object can only appear once in a set. Take a look at the set-related commands here: http://redis.io/commands/#set.

And an example using redis-cli (we attempt to add "Product One" twice, but it only appears once in the list of products):

```
$ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> sadd products "Product One"
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> sadd products "Product Two"
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> sadd products "Product Three"
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> sadd products "Product One"
(integer) 0
127.0.0.1:6379> smembers products
1) "Product Three"
2) "Product One"
3) "Product Two"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Comment: ...and if you need your "list" in order - use a Sorted Set :)

Comment: I need the order

Answer (score 4):

Why not just call `Redis.lrem` before? So if it finds any occurences of the item, removes them, otherwise will do nothing. Something like this:

```
def push_item_to_the_list(LIST_KEY, item)
   Redis.lrem(LIST_KEY, 0, item)
   Redis.lpush(LIST_KEY, item)
end
```

Comment: the position of my item is changed this way.

Answer (score 1):

This is my (reckless) solution to keep Redis List unique.
(implementation in Ruby)

```
def push_item_to_the_list(LIST_KEY, item)
 insert_status = Redis.linsert(LIST_KEY, 'before', item, item)

 if insert_status == -1
   Redis.lpush(LIST_KEY, item)
 else
   Redis.lrem(LIST_KEY, 1, item)
 end
end
```

Each time when you want to *push* or *insert* item to your list, check if `LINSERT` command will be able to put this item just after the very same item (this is the only way I know to check if the item is already in the redis list or not).

If `LINSERT` will return status -1, it means that it was not able to find item in your list - everything is ok (you can push it or insert it now).

If `LINSERT` will return other value (size of the list in other case) - it means that it was able to find item already and it was able to insert another item, just after the previous one. It means that you have (**at least** one) duplication of your item. You can delete one of them now.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to maintain the **order and the uniqueness** you can use a sorted set

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd products 1 "Product One"
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd products 2 "Product Two"
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd products 3 "Product Tree"
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd products 4 "Product Four"
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zrange products 0 -1
1) "Product One"
2) "Product Two"
3) "Product Tree"
4) "Product Four"
```

Comment: Is there a way to get a queue with unique items in redis? So a sorted set but I want to pop something from the front and then keep popping. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I propose an option that creates a unique list, the elements of which do not lose their position. This option works much faster than lpush, lrem, rpop. At the same time, it supports functional of sadd, spop.

PHP code example:

```php
public function addJobs(array $jobs): int
{
    foreach ($jobs as $key => $job) {
        $hash = hash('md4', $job);
        if (0 === $this->client->hsetnx('QUEUE-HASHES', $hash, 1)) {
            unset($jobs[$key]);
        }
    }

    return $this->client->rpush('QUEUE', $jobs);
}

public function popJobs(int $count): array
{
    if ($count < 1) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Jobs count must be greater than zero');
    }
    $index = $count - 1;
    $jobs = $this->client->lrange('QUEUE', 0, $index);
    if (\count($jobs)) {
        $this->client->ltrim('QUEUE', $count, -1);
        $hashes = [];
        foreach ($jobs as $job) {
            $hashes[] = hash('md4', $job);
        }
        $this->client->hdel('QUEUE-HASHES', $hashes);
    }

    return $jobs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> redis 5  ZPOPMIN https://redis.io/commands/zpopmin
>   Removes and returns up to count members with the lowest scores in the sorted set stored at key.

When left unspecified, the default value for count is 1. Specifying a count value that is higher than the sorted set's cardinality will not produce an error. When returning multiple elements, the one with the lowest score will be the first, followed by the elements with greater scores.

Answer (score 0):

I found this post looking for uniqueness in a List, since I wanted to refresh the list without duplicates and maintain the queued order over time.
This is a hybrid of a List and a Set/SortedSet so simply converting was not enough, leaving me with solving for uniqueness in a list or FIFO for a Set.

I found that coding for uniqueness in the List was quite simple, once i stopped looking for Redis type to handle that for me. Several people have mentioned this in the comments so I offer the following solution:

**TLDR: Use the existing list values to filter out duplicate incoming values**

NOTE: these examples are in Ruby but should be easy applied to other languages

Command Line example:

```rb
def items_to_queue
  ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
end

redis = Redis.new
# build the queue
redis.rpush(:my_queue, items_to_queue)
# verify the values are as expected
redis.lrange(:my_queue, 0, -1) # => ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
# remove some values
redis.lpop(:my_queue) # => "1"
redis.lpop(:my_queue) # => "2"

# While uniqueness is not a built in function of lists,
# we can use their values to filter the incoming values 
queued_values = redis.lrange(:my_queue, 0, -1) # => ["3", "4", "5"]
unqueued_values = items_to_queue - queued_values # => ["1", "2"]
# add the unqueued items to the queue
redis.rpush(:my_queue, unqueued_values)
# verify the values are as expected
redis.lrange(:my_queue, 0, -1) # => ["3", "4", "5", "1", "2"]
```

**BE EXPLICIT:**
The above code would not work if `items_to_queue` was defined to return integers instead of strings `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. Since Redis returns values as strings, the filtering would not work. In this case, the final output of this code would be: `["3", "4", "5", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]`.  Handle accordingly if you are dealing with type differences.

Object Example (my implementation):

```rb
  def items_to_queue
    ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
  end

  class RedisInstance
    cattr_accessor(*%i[redis])
    # to solve for a production error explained here: https://ogirginc.github.io/en/heroku-redis-ssl-error
    self.redis = Redis.new(ssl_params: { verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE })
  end

  class RedisList < RedisInstance
    attr_accessor(*%i[key])

    def initialize(key)
      self.key = key
    end

    def add_values(values, distinct: false)
      values -= self.values if distinct

      rpush(key, values) if values.present? # prevent Redis::CommandError if values ends up empty / nil
    end

    def first_value
      lpop(key)
    end
    alias next_value first_value

    # not used in this example but here for consistency
    def last_value 
      rpop(key)
    end

    def values(min: 0, max: -1)
      lrange(key, min, max)
    end

    private

    delegate(*Redis::Commands::Lists.instance_methods, to: :redis)
  end
```

```rb
  list = RedisList.new(:my_queue) => #<Redisable::List @key=:my_queue>
  list.add_values(items_to_queue, distinct: true)
  list.values # => ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
  list.next_value # => "1"
  list.next_value # => "2"
  list.add_values(items_to_queue, distinct: true)
  list.values # => ["3", "4", "5", "1", "2"]
```